# Adding category id or name to where clause $wpdb

Tags: sql, wordpress

This seems like it should be an easy answer but im struggling with this.  How can I add category ID to the where clause?  I have a bunch of post categories and I want to sort where category ID = 4 or category name = Restaurants.  Below is my working $wpdb get_results but without category id or name in the where clause. How do I add this?

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($currLat) ) * cos( radians( m1.meta_value ) ) * cos( radians( m2.meta_value ) - radians($currLong) ) + sin( radians($currLat) ) * sin( radians( m1.meta_value ) ) ) ) AS distance, m3.meta_value as bAddressOne, m1.meta_value as bLat, m2.meta_value as bLong, m4.meta_value as bOpenClose
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m1
    ON p.id = m1.post_id AND m1.meta_key = 'bLat'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m2
    ON p.id = m2.post_id AND m2.meta_key = 'bLong'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m3
    ON p.id = m3.post_id AND m3.meta_key = 'bAddressOne'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m4
    ON p.id = m4.post_id AND m4.meta_key = 'bOpenClose'
     WHERE post_type='el2-business' HAVING distance < $thedistance ORDER BY distance");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the 'category' taxonomy and interested in the posts with either term id 4 or term name 'Restaurants', the query would look something like:

```
...
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m4
    ON p.id = m4.post_id AND m4.meta_key = 'bOpenClose'
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr
    ON tr.object_id = ID
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
    ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'category'
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS t
    ON tt.term_id = t.term_id  
     WHERE (tt.term_id = 4 OR t.name = 'Restaurants') AND post_type='el2-business' HAVING distance < $thedistance ORDER BY distance");
```